# Safely remove a field from django model

Tags: python, django, migration

I removed some fields from my database lately and they are still in the older migration files of my project. I don't want to delete all the migration files, since they are in the git and it's not my project. But when I remove a field, the migration has problem because old migration files still have a "connection" to the deleted field.

Is there a way to delete a field without deleting migration files and without having any problems?

Thank you

Comment: You should *not* delete these by the database, but in the model, make (new) migrations, and  let Django's migration handle it.

Comment: Yes I know, i did remove the fields from the model, not from the database itself. But yet everytime i migrate, there is an error at any migration file that is about a field thats not in my model anymore

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already directly removed the field from database, follow the below steps to safely remove it from models.py:

Remove the field from model.
Run below migrations commands -

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

[NOTE]: NEVER directly remove the field from database.

Comment: Thanks for the information, this kinda worked. But the thing is I kinda messed it up and the migration files are pushed to the git, and some of the fields in older migration files don't exist anymore in the model.

Do I have to delete all the migration files?

Comment: Do not push migration files to git. Put it in .gitignore. 
Secondly, to solve your case after above steps you can push that to git. That will solve the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to push the migration files to git, it's mandatory for this project...

Comment: Anyway, after migrate --fake , you can push it to git. Should not be creating any issue at all. In case you are still facing any issue, provide the traceback log so I can help.

Comment: Thanks, I will try as soon as possible :)

Comment: you may mark and close this thread as accepted if the above answer solved your problem.